# Couchbeam - couchbeam_changes:follow_once times out prematurely

Tags: database, erlang, timeout, couchdb, long-polling

I'm trying to use the [Couchbeam](https://github.com/benoitc/couchbeam) `couchbeam_changes:follow_once` function with the following parameters:

```
{_, yield} = couchbeam_changes:follow_once(
   database,
   [
       longpoll,
       {since, seq},
       {heartbeat, 60000},
       {timeout, 60000},
       {filter, "_view"},
       {view, "match/date"}
   ]
)
```

There's no compilation error, but the call appears to timeout after just a few seconds, yielding - `{error, {closed, timeout}}`. Not the 60000ms I've set the time out for. Is there a bug in the library here?

Googling around, the closest issue I can find to mine, is this one:
https://github.com/benoitc/couchbeam/issues/132

Similar issue, different method.

For the record, my Couch instance is at v1.6.1

Comment: Has the CouchDB instance been running for some time, or is it starting along with the Erlang application?

Comment: There are a couple of issues here. First, '{"match", "date"}' is wrong. It should have been '{view, "match/date"}'. So I'll edit that. But, perhaps more vitally, I'm using an Erlang view for the changes feed... When I use a plain JavaScript view  in place of it, it works. So I;m not sure if this is a more fundamental CouchDB error.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, this was an issue in the library used to manage Couch DB. For anyone interested, the issue was fixed in this commit/pr:

https://github.com/benoitc/couchbeam/pull/147